# Should my unit tests for existing methods fail?

Tags: unit-testing

In TDD or BDD, we start from failing our unit tests, then fix the methods under test to let the unit tests pass.

Often times, at a new job, we need to write unit tests for existing methods. Probably not a good practice, but this does happen.  That's the situation I am in now.

So, here is my question: Should I let my unit tests for existing methods fail? Thank you.

Comment: Are you writing test for functions that already work, or for functions that need new functionality?

Comment: Methods that already work in the project, but lead would like to have unit tests for purpose of regression tests. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not try to make your tests fail.

Why does TDD make the test fail first?

The first reason is to ensure that you really are writing your tests before your code. If you write a test and it passes right away, you are writing code before your test. We write failing tests to be sure that we really are writing the tests first. In your case, its too late for that, so this reason doesn't apply.

A second reason is to verify that the tests are correct. The danger of a test is that it will not be testing the functionality that you think it is. Having the test fail for the correct reason gives confidence that the test is actually working. However, you cannot have the test fail for the correct reason. The code works, and the test is supposed to detect whether or not the good is working. So there is no way to write a test that actually fails for the correct reason.

You can, as the other answer suggested, write test code that is wrong, watch if fail and then correct it. But that fails because the test is wrong, its not really showing that your test correctly catches actual errors. At best it really shows that your assertions work. But generally we are pretty confident that the assertions work, and we don't need to constantly retest our assertions functions.

I don't think you gain much by trying to get your tests to fail when you are adding tests to already working code. So I wouldn't do it.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thank you. Now let's get back to the objective of such unit tests for existing methods. If some other day a  method under test is changed, and which causes the unit test to fail, the benefit of the unit test is to alert us that something has changed?

Comment: @Stack0verflow, ideally a unit test doesn't just tell you that something has changed. It should really only fail if something has become incorrect. Many times those are the same thing, but not always.

Answer (score 6):

You're not dealing with TDD when you're adding unit tests for working code. However, it is still a good idea to make the tests fail when you first write them (for example, in an extremely simple case, if the actual output will be `abc`, you write the test to expect `abd`) so that you know that the tests do fail when the output is different from what the test says is expected. Once you've proved that the tests can fail, you can make them pass by fixing the expected output.

The worst situation to be in is to add unit tests to working code that pass when they're first written. Then you modify the code, changing the output, and the unit tests still pass — when they shouldn't.  So, make sure your new unit tests do detect problems — which really does mean writing them so they fail at first (but that may mean you have to write them with known-to-be-bogus expected results).

Comment: Yes, I can deliberately make my tests fail by doing something like you said, for example, Assert.IsFalse(myObject.MethodUnderTestThatReturnsTrueIfTheParameterIsHello("Hello")); But, I wonder how much this helps since it is not some issue in the method under test that fails my unit test.

Comment: It helps you test your test framework, rather than the code.  If you're confident that you won't go astray, you don't have to make the tests fail first — but there are two bits of software that have to be tested: the system under test and the testing harness.